# Very slow boot due to rfkill - How to disable rfkill?

Tags: boot, rfkill

Ubuntu 20.04; dmesg shows that rfkill calls are taking about 26s of boot time:

```
[   10.111972] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[   16.059851] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   34.849174] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   41.532380] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   42.740710] audit: (...)
```

I find this rfkill call strange because this installation was never used in a machine with wi-fi hardware; both computers where this disk has been used have onboard ethernet, only.

I've tried to "disable" or "mask" rfkill, with no success.

```
user@ubuntu-fossa:/lib/systemd/system $ sudo systemctl disable rfkill 
Failed to disable unit: Unit file rfkill.service does not exist.
```

```
user@ubuntu-fossa:/lib/systemd/system $ sudo systemctl mask rfkill 
Unit rfkill.service does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/rfkill.service → /dev/null.
```

How can I definitely disable those rfkill calls at boot, or, at least, make then faster?

Answer (score 1):

It's weird but I solved this by changing 1's to 0's in the following settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

If you're on red hat, you can do that with

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6=1
```

followed by a reboot.